# Haskell, I keep getting "parse error on input `='"

Tags: haskell

I am working on the assignment.
I have no idea why I am getting this error.

I indicated the line where the error comes from by a comment.

And if you could (you don't have to), I don't think my `func` and `call` functions are working.

```
import Data.Maybe 

data Operator = Add | Sub | Mul | Div | And | Or | Not | Eq | Less | Great
  deriving (Eq, Show)
data Expression = Lit Value
         | Prim Operator [Expression]
         | Variable String
         | If Expression Expression Expression
         | Let [(String, Expression)] Expression
     | Func [String] Expression
     | Call Expression [Expression]
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data Value = Num Int
           | Bool Bool
       | Closure [String] Expression Environment
  deriving (Eq, Show)

type Environment = [(String, Value)]
--20
prim :: Operator -> [Value] -> Value
prim Add [Num a, Num b] = Num (a+b)
prim Mul [Num a, Num b] = Num (a*b)
prim Sub [Num a, Num b] = Num (a-b)
prim Div [Num a, Num b] = Num (a `div` b)
prim And [Bool a, Bool b] = Bool (a && b)
prim Or [Bool a, Bool b] = Bool (a || b)
prim Not [Bool a] = Bool (not a)
prim Eq [a, b] = Bool (a == b)
prim Less [Num a, Num b] = Bool (a < b)
prim Great [Num a, Num b] = Bool (a > b)
--32
evaluate :: Environment -> Expression -> Value
evaluate e (Lit v)  = v
evaluate e (Prim op as) = prim op (map (evaluate e) as)
evaluate e (Variable x) = fromJust (lookup x e)
evaluate e (If a b c)   = evaluate e (if fromBool (evaluate e a) then b else c)
evaluate e (Let bs b)   = evaluate ([(x, evaluate e d) | (x,d) <- bs ] ++ e) b

eval e (Func str ex) = (Closure str ex e) --40
evaluate e (Call ex exl) = let (Closure a b c) = (evaluate e ex) 
            in (Closure a b (c ++ (helper a (map (evaluate e) exl)))) 

helper :: [String] -> [Expression] -> [(String, Expression)]
helper (a:ar) (b:br) = (a, b) : helper ar br 

fromBool (Bool b) = b
--48
main = do
  let m = "m"
      k = Variable "k"  -- parse error on input `='
      y = Variable "y"
      lit m = Lit (Num m)
      a0 = Func [“k”] (Prim Mul [k, lit 2))
      in return $ Let [(“y”, a0)] (Prim Add [Call y [lit 3], Call y [lit 10]]) 
-- This is basically Let y = func(k) k*2 in y(3) + y(10) which returns 26.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Line 40 `eval` should be `evaluate` otherwise you are breaking up the definition of the `evaluate` function with some separate, unrelated, function named `eval`.
- Lines 54, 55.  You are using some unicode directional quotes, but should be using ASCii `"`.
- Line 54, you are using ')' when square brackets, ']', are needed.
- `helper` is not type correct and its typing breaks abstraction.  To make it correct you should change `Expression` to `Value`, but to keep with your abstraction you should make the result an `Environment`.

EDIT:

As I said, I changed helper's type signature to:

```
helper :: [String] -> [Value] -> [(String, Value)]
```

EDiT2:

Commenting on your edited code.  You have broken line 55 accidentily deleting a left paren:

```
Let ["y", a0)]  -- should be Let [("y", a0)]
```

And the line before that, you tried to fix a list that had a syntax error, `[ ... )`, but you changed the wrong bracket resulting in `( ...)` instead of the correct `[...]`:

Specifically:

```
[k, lit 2]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick response. But I think line 54 is fine, because if you look at where I define func in Expression, it looks like this: "Func [String] Expression"

Comment: You really think this is fine: `Prim Mul [k, lit 2)`?  My code parses, type checks and compiles - your code does not...  I leave it to you.

Comment: and for helper function, if you look at where I am calling it, it will evaluate exp like this, (map (eval e) exl), which returns Value. So, I think that should also be fine.  I am still getting the error...

Comment: Oops, I am sorry. You are right. I thought you were talking about ["k"] in front of it.

Comment: It still doesn't compile, I am still getting the same error from the same line.  I am very sorry but if you could elaborate my problem with helper, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Oh, yes! You are right. Sorry. I am still getting the same error from the same line... Although I corrected everything as you said. I feel so dumb.

Comment: @dockbudu, you said "assignment"; is this an assignment for a class?  Is going to your teacher for help an option?  That's what they're there for, you know.

Comment: @luqui Sorry about posting a question about my assignment. He is not available here right now... But sure, I ask him questions during his office hours.

Comment: @dockbudu if you still want more help then you'll need to edit your question and pute your current code at the bottom.

Comment: @Thomas M. DuBuisson Thank you very much, Mr.DuBuisson. I updated my code.

Comment: @dockbudu, it's okay, we're happy to help with homework.  It's just that I thought the kind of help you were looking for would be easier in person.

Comment: @dockbudu see my edit.  Understand that this is more help than people on SO usually give but the fact that you came with fully thought-out code and mostly syntax errors is meaningful.

Comment: Sorry about not being so careful about syntax. I thought what's causing this error was my logic, so I didn't pay much attention to that.  I think there are still some more syntax errors in my code. But I will figure it out. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Well, "parse error" means "syntax error". Compilers don't generally catch logic errors, although Haskell's strong typing makes logic errors more likely to cause other errors that the compiler can catch..